# How do i setup webpack for angular2 components that are using SASS and sharing common SASS imports?

Tags: angular, sass, webpack

I'm using Angular2, which basically lets me use sass files as styling tied to my components. So I have *many* individual sass files, since they are per component.

I have webpack set up for this, no problem.  I'm able to use SASS and the loaders are able to process it and everything gets bundled and minified.

**Here's where the problem comes in:**

In my particular example, i'm using the materializecss library (instead of bootstrap3, for once).

In order for me to use the materialize variables for breakpoints, colors, and other stuff, **I need to include the materializecss.scss file.**

This forces me to @import the giant scss file at the top of each of my component.scss files or else webpack throws errors at me that it doesn't understand the variables. But when i do this, I know for a fact, that webpack is duplicating this giant library each time, but I really want it to do it only once.

This is a common problem with sass in general, which is easily solved by creating a "main" file that is responsible for loading everything in order.  However, the fact that we are using component styles in this way for angular2 prevents me from being able to solve it that way.

It would be optimal, if I could configure webpack to BUNDLE the SCSS files in memory, first, and only then run a SASS loader over it.  This way, I only need to include materializecss.scss only once.  Is it possible?  Right now, behind the scenes, it seems that webpack is doing the sass->css conversion per file immediately, which is problematic.

Here's some simple examples:

Component1.scss

```css
// component1.scss

// next line is for visual studio intellisense
///<reference path="../../../node_modules/materialize-css/sass/materialize.scss" />

// I'm being forced to import the next line because webpack wont understand the media query.
@import "~materialize-css/sass/materialize.scss"; // Importing this too many times

@media #{$medium-and-down} {
    div {
        color: red;
    }
}
```

Component2.scss

```css
// component2.scss

// next line is for visual studio intellisense
///<reference path="../../../node_modules/materialize-css/sass/materialize.scss" />

// I'm being forced to import the next line because webpack wont understand the media query.
@import "~materialize-css/sass/materialize.scss"; // Importing this too many times

@media #{$medium-and-down} {
    span {
        color: blue;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am having this exact same issue with React + Webpack. For some reason webpack doesn't care that it's injecting the same CSS code multiple times.

You might want to look into running the webpack "dedupe" function when building for production (it can slow down dev quite a bit since its deduping after the fact I think, not just deduping imports) and also look into the "ExtractTextPlugin" to move the compiled styles to an external CSS file so it can be cached. In the mean time I'm ranting on github issues and Twitter about how poorly webpack was designed for CSS.

Comment: I'm glad someone's paying attention :) I've also seen discussions about this on github.  It's actually a general problem with Sass too (without angular), and people solve it by creating a "main" file that loads everything up in the correct order.  However in angular, it's added another layer of complication and that doesn't work anymore, since we want to use component styling.  For the time being, I am just not going to use variables in sass until a good solution is found.  If you come up with a solution, please come back here and reply ;)  I'll do the same.

Comment: Yeah I've just stopped using component specific imports for SCSS and I just do it all in one big style.scss import. That way I can use variables throughout my component scss files, but they are treated like normal stylesheets in the end.

Comment: I thought about it, but i sort of don't want to.  Not sure about react, but in angular2, the css selectors get into scoped/encapsulated versions which keeps the scope of the styles very tight.  You can be less wordy with your selectors and not worry about it affecting other components or other parts of your site.  It has its plus and minuses (sometimes you want your component to reach into another component's styles but can't...).